# Handler class and the timing of when its message queue is emptied

Tags: android

I was curious about the nature of the `handleMessage()` and `sendMessage()` behavior of the [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) class. I want to be able to send message to another thread in such a way that the destination thread can process the message queue when it wants to. It seems, however, that the message is processed by `handleMessage()` practically as soon as it's sent.

I'm trying to design a game loop thread that does something like this:

```
void run(){
   while (gameIsActive){
     handleInput();
     updateGameState();
   }
}

handleInput(){
  //Remove an item from the handler's message queue
  //which can be UI events (click, touch, etc.)
}
```

However, I as soon as sendMessage() is called (from the parent/calling thread), the Handler.handleMessage() is processed (in the child/receiving thread), even if the child/receiving thread is blocking in a while loop.

I've seen this problem solved in other games by using a thread-safe list (`ConcurrentLinkedQueue`). The UI thread just posts events to this queue, and the game loop can remove the events as it seems fit. I just assumed the Handler class was designed for this purpose. It seems it's more intended for asynchronous callbacks to the parent thread.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can't find a good answer about this timing (and it would be useful to know in other instances), but, as a workaround I just used a public List that was thread safe, and my UI thread can access this public list and add information to it.  In particular I used a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`. I found this in the official [JetBoy game sample](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/JetBoy/index.html) provided by Google, so maybe they don't even encourage using the Handler in this situation :)